# Upload PDF to Content Builder using REST

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, content-builder

Has anyone uploaded a PDF to Content Builder using REST? I think this is the Route, just not sure exactly how it works.

POST /asset/v1/content/assets

I see a few properties:

```
Data    object      Property bag containing the asset data
Content string      The actual content of the asset
```

Looking to upload the PDF in Content Builder for use as an Email Attachment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per your post I was able to upload a pdf file into sfmc content builder. It took me a little while to gather all the necessary attributes but it is all available in [REST Reference API.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm)

Here are the steps and things to consider:

- Make sure the API user account has Assets **read** and **write** access.
- Your pdf file that needs to be uploaded to the content builder needs to be Base64Encoded which you can convert using this [website](https://www.base64encode.org/).
- If you wish to upload the pdf file to a specific folder within content builder then you need to specify the folder **ID** and **name** within the **category** object attribute.
- Also proper **assetType** needs to be set for specific type of file - in your situation it is name as **pdf** and id as **127**.
- Also I am using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/apps) to test this scenario.
- Below is the sample request which works successfully:

**Header**

- POST
- Content-Type: application/json
- Authorization: Bearer **{{accessToken}}**
- URL: https://www.exacttargetapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets

**Body**

`{
  "name": "pdf name to be uploaded",
  "assetType": {
    "name": "pdf",
    "id": 127
   },
  "category": {
    "id": 123456 (ID of the folder) ,
    "name": "name of folder where pdf is uploaded"
  },
  "file": "xxxxxBase64Encoded-Filexxxxx"
}`

Comment: On an unrelated note: for id/name attributes like assetType and category, only the id is required. The name is useful for display purposes on GET but will be ignored on POST/PUT/PATCH.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was able to successfully add a file.

Comment: Just a friendly comment, you don't need to pass category name is the payload as id is all you need