# Content Builder: Automated Image creation from URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, soap-api, ssjs, content-builder

I want to establish an automated image creation that pulls images from URLs to content builder and automatically saves or overrides them, because i want to use these images in emails and i believe getting those images via HTTP.get for each email seems a bad idea[is it?].

Inside the SOAP / AMPScript and SSJS i did not find a function that creates Content inside Content Builder (i only saw Scripts [that create Dataextensions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createDataExtension.htm) or stuff like [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/objectdefinition.htm))

Can i create an automation like this within automation studio?

Comment: you can use SSJS to build a REST API framework that can help you create images, however, you'd need to base64encode the assets (images/pdf)

Comment: this might be useful in terms of API however if you need the SSJS script i can provide that too https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/197185/upload-pdf-to-content-builder-using-rest/197252#197252

Comment: Also, you have mentioned that these images are available upon GET request, I guess if the image server is reliable and faster as compared to marketing cloud's server, you could just go down that path. Unless the requirement is to have all images in SFMC